# I'm looking for specific matrices to plug into a convolution matrix

Tags: graphics, matrix, filter, convolution

Assuming I already have a working convolution matrix algorithm in place, I'm looking for practical examples of general matrices that are useful for image processing in particular.

The canonical examples you'll find everywhere are non-gaussian box blur:

```
1 1 1
1 1 1
1 1 1
```

Image sharpening:

```
 0  -1   0
-1   5  -1
 0  -1   0
```

Edge detection:

```
0  1  0
1 -4  1
0  1  0
```

and emboss:

```
-2 -1  0
-1  1  1
 0  1  2
```

Are there more I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

have you ever played with jitter, the image processing framework that's part of max/msp? There are a lot of examples of convolution matrices within the example patches, and it's an extremely flexible algorithm prototying environment.

http://cycling74.com

One thing that comes to mind immediately that's not in your list is feedback, but that's usually more interesting in a video context.