# General matrix definition for image filtering or trasnformation

Tags: image, image-processing, matrix

I am looking for matrices I can generate to transform other matrices, but I am not talking about regular matrices like:

---

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810094/im-looking-for-specific-matrices-to-plug-into-a-convolution-matrix): The canonical examples you'll find everywhere are non-gaussian box blur:

```
1 1 1
1 1 1
1 1 1
```

Image sharpening:

```
 0  -1   0
-1   5  -1
 0  -1   0
```

Edge detection:

```
0  1  0
1 -4  1
0  1  0
```

and emboss:

```
-2 -1  0
-1  1  1
 0  1  2
```

---

Those are for applying to each region of an image, I just want a big matrix. Is that possible?

For example: A 2560*2560 matrix that I can multiply directly with an image of 2560*2560 pixels.

Comment: You want use matrix multiplication instead of convolution. This is a different things!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible, but maybe not in the way you would think. Take a look at the Gaussian blur example at http://scipy-lectures.github.io/intro/scipy.html#fast-fourier-transforms-scipy-fftpack

The thing is that convolution in the image is equivalent to multiplication in the frequency domain. This is the Convolution Theorem from Fourier Transforms (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Convolution_theorem). So, it is possible -- and in fact for huge images like you're talking about it should be faster. But the matrices are no longer simple ones like the examples you posted above.